# Complete form based on drop down selection

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple form that requires employees to input phone numbers, employee ID, etc. I would like to save them some time (and prevent data entry errors) by allowing them to select their name form a drop down and have the text input fields for phone and ID number autofill based on the name selected.

I have an HTML table that contains all the employee information, but do not know how to pass that information to the proper fields. Code snippet follows:

```css
#emp_data_tbl {
  width: 90%
}

#emp_data_tbl td,
#emp_data_tbl th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

#emp_data_tbl tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

#emp_data_tbl tr:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#emp_data_tbl th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<p>Name</p>
<select required>
  <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Choose Name...
  </option>
  <option value="Adam Jackson">Adam Jackson
  </option>
  <option value="Bill Smith">Bill Smith
  </option>
  <option value="Chris Clinton">Chris Clinton
  </option>
  <option value="David Billings">David Billings
  </option>
  <option value="Eamon Lampsen">Eamon Lampsen
  </option>
</select>


<p>Phone</p>
<input type="text" id="phone">

<p>ID</p>
<input type="text" id="IdNum">


<br><br>
<hr><br><br>


<table id="emp_data_tbl">
  <caption>In reality, this data table is hidden with CSS display: none but viewable here in this mock up</caption>
  <col>
  <col>
  <col>

  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Phone</th>
    <th>ID</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Adam Jackson</td>
    <td>111-111-1111</td>
    <td>#1111</td>
  </tr>


  <tr>
    <td>Bill Smith</td>
    <td>222-222-2222</td>
    <td>#2222</td>
  </tr>


  <tr>
    <td>Chris Clinton</td>
    <td>333-333-3333</td>
    <td>#3333</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>David Billings</td>
    <td>444-444-4444</td>
    <td>#4444</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Eamon Lampsen</td>
    <td>555-555-5555</td>
    <td>#5555</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: What is the point having hidden table with Employees info on the page?

Comment: I guess whether it's hidden or not isn't really germane to the problem I'm facing. The original function of the table is administrative so people in the office know contact information ect for other workers. It's hidden when THIS part of the page is being viewed because it's not relevant to the form being filled out, except as a look up table to bring information associated with them employee into the text input fields.

Comment: Your HTML is incorrect for the select/option tags https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp

Comment: Using a hidden `HTML` table isn't that smart choice, I think it's better to make a `JavaScript` array variable that holds employees objects(name, id, etc...) then add an event listener to the dropdown menu and fill the fields using the array.

Answer (score 2):

This will get you started.

```css
#emp_data_tbl {
  width: 90%
}

#emp_data_tbl td,
#emp_data_tbl th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

#emp_data_tbl tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

#emp_data_tbl tr:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#emp_data_tbl th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
 <form action="#">
  <label for="name">Name</label><br>
  <select id="name" name="name"></select><br><br>
  <!--<label for="female">Phone</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone"><br><br>
  <label for="id">ID</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="id" id="id"><br><br>-->
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

<br><br>
<hr><br><br>


<table id="emp_data_tbl">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Phone</th>
      <th>ID</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Adam Jackson</td>
      <td>111-111-1111</td>
      <td>#1111</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bill Smith</td>
      <td>222-222-2222</td>
      <td>#2222</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Chris Clinton</td>
        <td>333-333-3333</td>
        <td>#3333</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>David Billings</td>
          <td>444-444-4444</td>
          <td>#4444</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eamon Lampsen</td>
      <td>555-555-5555</td>
      <td>#5555</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>

var rows = document.getElementById("emp_data_tbl").rows;
var users = [];
var phonenrs = [];
var ids = [];

//start at i = 1 to skip the header row
for(var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++)
{
    users.push(rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML);
    phonenrs.push(rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML);
    ids.push(rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML);
}

var nameList = document.getElementById("name");

for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++)
{
    nameList.add(new Option(users[i], users[i] + " - " + phonenrs[i] + " - " + ids[i]));
}

</script>
```

After this, you will need to do something when your user chooses his name.
You can do this by adding an onChange to the selectbox, which holds a function that will be executed the moment the user chooses an option of the selectbox. For example:

```
<select id="name" name="name" onchange="fillData();"></select>
```

After this, you can create a Javascript function fillData(), that get's the telephone number and id, belonging to the user and fill in the values with javascript. Something like:

```
function fillData(){ 
document.getElementById("phone").value = ""; 
//get and set your id and phone values here 
}
```

Comment: Thanks @dmat. I can see it's grabbing the phone number and ID because when I click your Submit button, they show up in the URL. I removed the comment block tags on the phone and ID input boxes so they are visible on the page, but the phone and ID values do not populate those input boxes.

Comment: Hello @kroy2008, I think it is best to learn some Javascript, for example on https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp. You can add an onChange to the selectbox, so it will do something when your user selects their name. Like:
<select id="name" name="name" onchange="fillData();"></select>

After this, you can create a Javascript function fillData(), that get's the telephone number and id, belonging to the user and fill in the values with javascript. Something like:
function fillData(){
document.getElementById("phone").value = "";
//get and set your id and phone values here

}